# bash script fails when password contains backtick

Tags: linux, bash

A colleague wrote a script that acts as a wrapper for executing other scripts remotely. It is set up to ask for a password which is then `echo`'ed to remote systems for use in `sudo`.

Relevant code*:

```
read -s pw
....
${SSH_tt} ${HOST} "echo ${pw} | ${SUDO_S} ./${SCRIPT_NAME} > ${HOME}/${HOST_OUTPUT}" 2> /dev/null
```

* Please ignore the all upper-case variables.

If I enter a password which contains a backtick I get the following error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I change my password to one that does not contain the backtick the script runs fine. I imagine it would happen with passwords which contain single- and double-quotes as well.

While changing my password is an option it is not desirable due to the size of our platform (we don't use centralized authentication). I'm wondering if there is a way to sanitize or otherwise escape the backtick so that it isn't interpreted by the shell either locally or remotely.

Comment: A better solution is to configure `sudo` on the remote end to allow you to run the script without a password. Your script exposes the password as clear text in the output of, e.g., `ps`.

Comment: This is not an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the password before you execute the last line.

In bash:

```
escaped_pw=`printf "%q" ${pw}`
```

Then use `escaped_pw` in place of `pw`.

```
${SSH_tt} ${HOST} "echo ${escaped_pw} | ${SUDO_S} ./${SCRIPT_NAME} > ${HOME}/${HOST_OUTPUT}" 2> /dev/null
```

Here's an example :

```
$ read -s pw
$ echo $pw
ronak`gandhi
$ escaped_pw=`printf "%q" ${pw}`
$ echo $escaped_pw
ronak\`gandhi
$ ssh myhost "echo ${escaped_pw} - `date`"
ronak`gandhi - Thu Jun 18 19:28:47 PDT 2015
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. If you don't mind, can you give me a synopsis of what is happening?

Comment: Although you quoted the password on the local end, the string is evaluated again on the remote host, so the backquote is treated as the beginning of a command substitution.